# Aligning offset data values sql join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Currently, I've got two rows of data pivoted using case statement into two columns. Data is not aligning. Within the case statement, is there a way to align? All values in Column A has a corresponding value in Column B.

```
+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
| Null     | 0        |
+----------+----------+
| 40       | Null     |
+----------+----------+
| Null     | 0        |
+----------+----------+
| 50       | Null     |
+----------+----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
| 40       | 0        |
+----------+----------+
| 50       | 0        |
+----------+----------+
```

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN t.[column A] = 'Column A' THEN t.value END) AS [Column A],
       (CASE WHEN t.[column B] = 'Column B' THEN t.value END) AS [Column B]
FROM t INNER JOIN t1 ON t.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.string = '123455'
```

[image]

Comment: please show your pivot query

Comment: @Squirrel     
Select
 (Case when t.column A = 'Column A' Then t.value end) As Column A,
 (Case when t.column B= 'Column B' Then t.value end) As Column B  From t
Inner Join t1 on t.ID=t1.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cross apply` should work for this requirement since there's no conditions.

```
select t.colA, max(t.ColB) from(
   select t1.colA, t2.colB from testA t1
   cross apply testA t2
   where t1.colA is not null) t
 group by t.colA
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b55bf/28/0)

Comment: Currently, i'm joining with another table to pull in data based on an ID number. Is there a way to include an inner join?

Comment: yes, you can join other table, based on ID number. just include your ID on this query.

Comment: added in an image reference of what I've got thus far.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  In a sense, there is no way to answer your question, although this would work:

```
select a, 0 as b
from t
where a is not null;
```

However, I suspect that you want to align values based on the ordering.  For that, you need an ordering column.  Something like this should work:

```
select max(a) as a, max(b) as b
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by <ordering col>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor( (seqnum - 1) / 2 );  -- floor() is not really needed
```

For this to work, though, you need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: My columns are actually rows within the same table. I'm using case when to pivot as columns. When doesn't this is when my mis-match occurs.

Comment: Added an image view of what I've got thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t2.weight, t1.invalid
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.sequence = t1.sequence
where t1.weight is null
and t2.invalid is null
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I nest this within my current query? Both weight and invalid are from the same column.

Comment: @Diego83 If you use my query on your result set as shown in your image then you should get the final result set you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have put sample data and tried the below. It is working fine. You can use Window functions & GROUP BY aggregate to arrive at the result.

```
CREATE TABLE #test1 (seq int, columna int, columnb int)

INSERT INTO #test1 
values (0,99,null), (0,null,0)

select * from #test1

select seq, MAX(case when rnk_columna = 1 then columna else 0 end) as columna, MAX(case when rnk_columnb = 1 then columnb else 0 end) as columna
from
 (select seq, columna, columnb, Row_number() over(partition by seq order by columna desc) as rnk_columna, Row_number() over(partition by seq order by columnb desc) as rnk_columnb
from #test1) as t
group by seq
```